# Row with truncating text and elements that stick to the right

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the layout I need to achieve:

```
   1               2                 3                                  4
____________________________________________                    ________________
|     |                         |          |                    |              |
|  *  |  Potentially Long Text  |  ******  |                    |  **********  |
|_____|_________________________|__________|                    |______________|
```

If the text in element 2 becomes so long that 3 bumps into 4, the text should be truncated and an ellipsis appended. Neither the contents of any element or the elements themselves should ever wrap.

I first tried making each element `inline-block`, but that won't let 4 to stick to the right. Floating it right causes it to wrap down below the rest of the row when container is resized small enough; rather, element 2 should get smaller.

I then tried doing this with a table, but I can't get the text in 2 to truncate with hard-coding a (max) width. (See http://jsfiddle.net/W7QLj/1/)

Basically, 2 should be as small as necessary to contain all the text, 4 should stick to the right, there shouldn't be space between 2 and 3, and if we run out of space, 2 should get smaller fit everybody. Element 4's width is variable.

Can anybody suggest a strategy to get the behavior I need? I'm prepared to throw in some javascript if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend to use a **grid**. I immediately thought of Cris Coyiers: "Don't overthink it grids". See: http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/

```
<div class="grid"> 
  <div class="col-1-4">
    <div class="module">
      <h3>box1</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-1-4">
   ....
</div>
```

Using his code I made it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/W7QLj/74/

Try adding more text to box2. Hope this helps, since it does not include everything you want:)